# why some website did not show replay xhr in Google Chrome DevTools

Tags: google-chrome

Today I found some url show `Replay XHR`, but some url not. For example, this request did not show `Replay XHR`. But most of website show `Replay XHR`, so why some url did not show `Replay XHR`? the `Replay XHR` only support https? My google chrome version:`Version 90.0.4430.85 (Official Build) (x86_64)`.

[image]